# I want to extract the data from a Bigquery Column in three different columns in Bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table of Bigquery which has data In three different columns. The columns are projectname,datasetname and accessentries. It's a list of datasets with their access entries but in accessentries the data is in multiple forms i.e like <AccessEntry: role=WRITER, groupbyEmail=gchbpd@gmail.com>,<AccessEntry: role=owner, groupbyEmail=ntpd@gmail.com>,<AccessEntry: role=READER, groupbyEmail=gchbd@cgmail.com> etc etc this all data is present in a single row. I want them to be In seperate row and I want that dataset name should be repeated I front of their accessentries. Also I want role to be in different column, 'groupbyEmail' in different column and gchbpd@gmail.com in different Column. The values are dynamic in entire column. Can someone please help me out?

I used Regex function but the issue is I am able to extract the arrays in different rows but I am failing to create a new Column for row and other two things. I cannot extract the exact information.

Comment: Can you share what did you try? Can you also share a sample of the expected result (and the entry also)?

Comment: select project_name, dataset_name, access_entries, extracted_data,
TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(extracted_data, r'role=([^,]+)')) AS Role,
from

 select project_name, dataset_name, access_entries, TRIM(unnested_entry) AS extracted_data,

from

akbo-hcb.lest_permission,

UNNEST (REGEXP EXTRACT_ALL(access_entries, r'<AccessEntry: [^>]+>')) AS unnested entry
)

Comment: I have three columns projectname, datasetname & AcessEntries. In accessentries I have the data in a form which is shared in orignal question. I want to extract it the way I said in question. I need 5 columns projectname datasetname AcessEntries role category and entity where role category and entity is to be extracted from accessentries

Comment: If I asked, it's because it's not clear enough. WHat's your accessentries type? Repeated String? Repeated struct? Only a string with <...> values separated with a comma as shared in your question?

Comment: Accessentries type is repeated string.

Comment: Multiple values <...> Seperated with a comma. But it's in string format. Kindly let me know if you have any more questions.